# Who is the Greatest Classic Rock Band of All Time?

Tags: knowledge, crosswords, music

This is not a "normal" crossword, but the clues are pretty normal, i.e. they're not [cryptic-clues](/questions/tagged/cryptic-clues). The words you put into the boxes, though, aren't the answers to the clues, they're just related.

It's not really *that* complicated, but in order to clarify, my lawyer has provided the following statement:

> Heretoforthwith, each Answer (hereinafter called The "A") that is derived from the Clues (hereinafter called the "C"s) will **not** be placed into the Boxes (hereinafter called the "B"s) provided by the Formulator (hereinafter called the "F") of said Crossword.
>   The letters that are put into the "B"s will be relevant "A"s of the "C"s and the number of letters to be placed into each "B" is denoted in parentheses at the end of each "C" in the notation (##).

I trust that this statement clears up any questions you may have.

The ☑ will go to the first person to
a) provide the phrase that is hidden in the completed puzzle
b) answer the "F"s answer to the Title Question.

### R O C K -N- R O L L

[image: ![![enter image description here]

### ACROSS

1 --- Escalate to the Great Beyond (11)
4 --- Flickering Flare (9)
7 --- What Philanthropists do with money (18)
15 -- Fountain Pen Delivery Unit (12)
16 -- Almost all my Cards are Spades, Clubs, and Diamonds (3)
17 -- Cosmos Convoy (10)
19 -- "Johnny, your sheets smell *terrible!*" (7)
21 -- Wounded by Passion (8)
22 -- Nocturnal Aviation (4)
25 -- You Disturbed me from Dusk 'till Dawn (4)
26 -- Evaluating the Pros and Cons of my Current Wherabouts (5)
29 -- Unparalleled, Skeletally (15)
30 -- ¡Cálmate! (6)

### DOWN

2 --- Are you Coming with Me? (12)
3 --- Ambulate, like so (9)
5 --- Loco Loco (12)
6 --- He who Tickles Ivory (9)
8 --- Vicious Fishes (5)
9 --- Circling the Disposal Unit (8)
10 -- Passports to Hawaii? (10)
11 -- How I Describe my Mother-In-Law (22)
12 -- Left at Bellevue (18)
13 -- Step *Back*, Jack! (6)
14 -- Paralyzed in a Barcalounger (9)
18 -- Correct: "Favorite" Correct: "Favourite" (2)
20 -- BOGO Chicken (13)
23 -- Let's Powerlessly Travel Overseas (4)
24 -- Toss You Cyclonically (9)
27 -- Steady Stream (8)
28 -- Roy Rogers in the 21st Century (5)

BTW, the word "The" will not go into any of the boxes.

[Guitar Image credits](https://pixabay.com/en/music-guitar-rock-sound-acoustic-160285/)

Comment: obviously it's "Queen"

Comment: @Buildstarted Is this the first of what may be many "personal opinion answers" to the Title Question? (－‸ლ)

Comment: Quantum Twinkie was on a roll, but deleted his answer. :(

Comment: @DanielSchepler by my calcs; the 5th letter of that one is 'r'

Comment: Ah, right, never mind then.

Comment: I bet 14 Down is rot13(pbzsbegnoyl ahzo - cvax syblq).

Comment: As of the time noted [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/63281/who-is-the-greatest-classic-rock-band-of-all-time#comment192583_63281), It seems that only **29 Across; 5, 13, 20 and 27 Down** remain unanswered. 5 down has been alluded to in a comment, though.

Comment: I think that's all of them, @Chowzen

Comment: That's the crossword puzzle, yes, @Buildstarted. Now I hope  everyone hasn't forgotten the actual goal here: ***The ☑ will go to the first person to
a) provide the phrase that is hidden in the completed puzzle
b) answer the "F"s answer to the Title Question.***

Comment: Geez man, this question - are you looking to start a brawl here? :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hidden phrase: **amazing!**

> Taking the first letter of each answer **LLAEOBRHTEESPPBYDUNLNRSSACPTGE** and unscrambling it you get the hidden phrase "Sgt Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band"
>  
>  Because of the nature of this puzzle the answer to the title question is **The Beatles**

Most answers by [Daniel Schepler](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/46631/daniel-schepler), [Alan Hoover](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/46886/alan-hoover), and [Pugmonkey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/45919/pugmonkey) - my four highlighted

### Across

1: Escalate to the Great Beyond

> Stairway to Heaven - Led Zeppelin

4: Flickering flare

> Candle In The Wind - Elton John

7: What Philanthropists do with money

> Give It Away - Red Hot Chili Peppers

15: Fountain Pen Delivery Unit

> N.I.B (Nativity In Black) - Black Sabbath

16: Almost all my Cards are Spades, Clubs, and Diamonds

> Owner Of A Lonely Heart - Yes

17: Cosmos Convoy

> Space Truckin' - Deep Purple

19: "Johnny, your sheets smell terrible!"

> Smells Like Teen Spirit - Nirvana

20: Wounded by passion

> Love Hurts - Nazareth

22: Nocturnal Aviation

> Fly By Night - Rush

25: You Disturbed me from Dusk 'till Dawn

> You Shook Me All Night Long - AC/DC

26: Evaluating the pros and cons of my current position

> Should I Stay Or Should I Go - The Clash

**29: Unparalleled, Skelletally**

> Bad to the Bone - George Thorogood

30: ¡Cálmate!

> Take It Easy - Eagles

### Down

2: Are you Coming with Me?

> Are You Gonna Go My Way - Lenny Kravitz

3: Ambulate, like so

> Aerosmith - walk this way

5: Loco Loco

> Crazy Train - Ozzy Osbourne

6 Down: He who tickles ivory

> The Piano Man - Billy Joel

8: Vicious Fishes

> Barracuda - Heart

9 Down: Circling the disposal unit

> Running Down A Dream - Tom Petty

10: Passports to Hawaii?

> Two Tickets To Paradise - Eddie Money

11: How I Describe my Mother-In-Law

> Evil Woman - Electric Light Orchestra

12: Left at Bellevue (18)

> Institutionalized - Suicidal Tendencies

**13: Step *Back*, Jack!**

> Don't Stand So Close To Me - Police

14: Paralyzed in a Barcalounger

> Comfortably Numb - Pink Floyd

18: Correct: "Favorite" Correct: "Favourite"

> With Or Without You - U2

**20: BOGO Chicken (this one is my favorite)**

> Free bird - Lynyrd Skynyrd

23: Let's powerlessly travel overseas

> "Come Sail Away". B: Styx.

24: Toss You Cyclonically

> Scorpions - rock you like a hurricane

**27: Steady Stream**

> Even Flow - Pearl Jam

28: Roy Rogers in the 21st Century

> Modern Day Cowboy - Tesla

Helpful image

> [image]

Comment: ***Very*** nice work! +1!

Comment: This is a very nice puzzle, @chowzen!

Comment: So, that would obviously make the F's answer to the title question...

Comment: Can you add explanations to the answer? As it stands I don't have a clue of where the hidden phrase came from.

Comment: updated the answer, @ffao

Comment: You reversed the order for 8 down (“Heart - Barracuda” instead of “Barracuda - Heart”).

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean [Peter Frampton and the Bee Gees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sgt._Pepper%27s_Lonely_Hearts_Club_Band_(film))?

Answer (score 13):

Some possible answers...

4 Across: Flickering flare (9)

> A: "Candle in the wind."  B: Elton John.

7 Across: What philanthropists do with money (18)

> A: "Give it away now."  Which would likely make B - Red Hot Chili Peppers.

16 Across: Almost all my Cards are Spades, Clubs, and Diamonds (3)

> A: "Owner of a lonely heart".  B: Yes.

19 Across: "Johnny, your sheets smell terrible!" (7)

> A: "Smells like teen spirit", B: Nirvana?  (uncertain about this one)

20 Across: Wounded by passion (8)

> A: "Love hurts".  B: Nazareth.

25 Across: You disturbed me from dusk 'till dawn (4)

> A: "You shook me all night long."  B: AC/DC

26 Across: Evaluating the pros and cons of my current position (5)

> A: "Should I stay or should I go?"  B: (The) Clash

6 Down: He who tickles ivory (9)

> A: "The Piano Man."  B: Billy Joel.

9 Down: Circling the disposal unit (8)

> A: "Running Down the Drain".  Which could be a common mishearing of "Running Down a Dream", so B: Tom Petty?

23 Down: Let's powerlessly travel overseas (4)

> A: "Come Sail Away".  B: Styx.

Comment: Wow, you're onto something! Sorry bout the "Drain," I was on [kissthisguy.com](http://www.kissthisguy.com/running-down-a-dream-tom-petty-and-the-h-misheard-song-5890.htm) looking stuff up today. :)

Answer (score 11):

A few to get started

Across

1 --- Escalate to the Great Beyond (11)

> : Led Zeppelin - stairway to heaven

7 --- What Philanthropists do with money (18):

> Red Hot Chili Peppers  - give it away

15 -- Fountain Pen Delivery Unit (12)

> Black Sabbath – nativity in black (NIB)

17 -- Cosmos Convoy (10):

> Deep Purple  - space truckin'

22 -- Nocturnal Aviation (4):

> Rush - fly by night

25 -- You Disturbed me from Dusk 'till Dawn (4)

> : ACDC  - you shook me all night long

30 -- ¡Cálmate! (6)

> : Eagles - <s>desparado</s> Take it easy per Daniel Schepler

Down

2 --- Are you Coming with Me? (12)

> : Lenny Kravitz  - are you gonna go my way

3 --- Ambulate, like so (9)

> :  Aerosmith  - walk this way

5 --- Loco Loco (12) :

> Ozzy Osbourne - Crazy Train per @Herb Wolfe and hint from @Chowzen

8 --- Vicious Fishes (5)

> :  Heart  - barracuda

10 -- Passports to Hawaii? (10)

> :  Eddie Money  - two tickets to paradise

11 -- How I Describe my Mother-In-Law (22):

> Electric light Orchestra – <s>Turn to Stone</s> I guess Evil woman does make more sense than the Medusa reference

14 -- Paralyzed in a Barcalounger (9):

> Pink Floyd – Comfortably numb per @Riley

18 -- Correct: "Favorite" Correct: "Favourite" (2)

> U2 – with or without you

24 -- Toss You Cyclonically (9)

> : Scorpions  - rock you like a hurricane

Comment: I think on 30, A is actually rot13 of "gnxr vg rnfl".

Comment: Rntyrf? YES.  qrfcnenqb? no.

Comment: Oynpx Fnoongu? no. The rest are looking good

Comment: I think 5 may be a different song by the lead singer.

Answer (score 8):

ACROSS

15 -- Fountain Pen Delivery Unit (12)

> "N.I.B." (Nib) -- Black Sabbath

DOWN

5 --- Loco Loco (12)

> "Crazy, Mad, Insane" -- Beast in Black

11 -- How I Describe my Mother-In-Law (22)

> "Evil Woman" -- Electric Light Orchestra (I hope she doesn't see this)

12 -- Left at Bellevue (18)

> "Institutionalized" -- Suicidal Tendencies

18 -   Correct: "Favorite" Correct: "Favourite" (2)

> "With or Without You"  U2

28 -- Roy Rogers in the 21st Century (5)

> "Modern Day Cowboy" -- Tesla

Comment: oooOOOOOooooohhhh!!! *Nice.*

Comment: I'm amazed that there's yet another 12 letter A that (more or less) fits Loco Loco, but I think the correct, intended A fits much better.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure about that one (3 "locos" instead of 2). I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 4):

As nobody bothered adding this, I think that the greatest band of all time is:

> The Beatles

with the hidden phrase as per the answer of @Buildstarted

> Sgt Pepper's Lonely Hearts Club Band which is an anagram of the first letters of all the bands in the crossword.

Credits go to:
@Buildstarted, @DanielSchepler, @Pugmonkey and @AlanHoover

> Disclaimer: I strongly disagree with the Formulator :)